# How can I verify that AutoHistory is working in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to use the Visual Studio [AutoHistory extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dfcb2438-180c-4f8a-983b-62d89e141fe3).

However, when I select "Take Snapshot" (except for the very first time), I see no difference in the AutoHistory pane. The "Old" timestamp remains the same and the "Now" edit box (and "X" to its right) are read-only:

[image]

How can I verify that my snapshots are really being taken? I feel as if the lens cap is still on the camera or something. How can I compare my last two snapshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to look at the filename list with the 'old' and 'new' columns.  Instead you really need to hover over those tiny snapshot entries to get information on when AutoHistory is doing the captures.  If you want to change the label of a snapshot, seems like the interface requires you to grab the top of the little range box and drag it down to *just above* the item in question. Only then does it seem to allow your snapshot's label to be changed:

So, drag this box...

[image]

...down to this spot, right above the snapshot you just took:

[image]

And, apparently, a snapshot's label value is changed when the textbox looses focus (there's little indication that you've updated the text).

If you want to compare two snapshots, you have to painstakingly set the box's bounds to that of the two snapshots you want to compare:
[image]

I do like the power of this extension, but the interface can be maddening and isn't very intuitive.
Looks like the author(s) have abandoned support for it since they no longer reply to comments or requests.  Would be awesome if it were open source since it just needs a few tweaks to really take this thing across the finish line!